# Graphite: graphs not rendering, image cannot be displayed because it contains errors

Tags: graphite

I am new to graphite. After setting it up, I ran into the issue that no graphs can be viewed (or plotted) but everything else seems fine. If I tried to open the graph directly from its url it says "The image http://.... cannot be displayed because it contains errors".

Below is the output in console when I tried clicked on `loadavg_1min` and displayed it:

```
[03/Aug/2015 21:07:06]"GET /render/?width=1041&height=542&_salt=1438661217.502 HTTP/1.1" 200 4
- Broken pipe from ('127.0.0.1', 52538)
```

There are nothing special about my setup, I use a Mac 10.10 and totally follow the documentation to follow the initialization, everything is default except the `CARBONLINK_HASHING_KEYFUNC` in local_settings.py, which I set it to "None". And I followed this link to get started: http://graphite.wikidot.com/quickstart-guide.

I will provide more information if that is needed. Thank you in advance!

In my Graphite Browser, the Graphite Composer just shows a broken image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check the error at `http://yourGraphiteServer.com/dashboard`. It gives you a complete python traceback.

As far as the broken images are concerned, its the cairocffi package that handles the font and the image rendering. The traceback at the above URL should show that the cairocffi package is missing. You should install cairocffi with all the dependencies resolved.

`pip install cairocffi` will do the job.

[This](https://github.com/SimonSapin/cairocffi) the Github page for cairocffi.

Comment: Following this I finally got the graph. But no legend and units along x/y axis  are chaotic.

Comment: The graphite web console gives you complete control over the units and axis management. Please check the three buttons at the bottom in the graph window.

Comment: Hope I could show you the screen shot, the units are just some unreadable things... guess there is some problem with my cairo on mac, I finally made it work on my linux virtual machine. Just wonder whether someone else has ever ran into the same problem.

Comment: I would get back to you. I think I know this issue. If the answer was useful, accept it. That will help others in the proper direction, because the installing graphite and getting it up and running is a bumpy ride.